# Finding Length of an integer with zeros in C++?

Tags: c++, integer

I want to find length of the integer with preceding zeros

```
int intLength(int num)
{
    int l = 0;
    while(num>0)
    {
        num = num/10;
        l++;
    }
    return l;
}
```

- intLength(1)      ==> 1
- intLength(0)      ==> 0  Expected: 1
- intLength(10)     ==> 2
- intLength(100)    ==> 3
- intLength(01)     ==> 1  Expected: 2
- intLength(0100)   ==> 2 Expected: 4

Comment: Shouldnt `intLentght(10)` ==>2?

Comment: There is no such thing as a leading zero in an int representation.  1 == 01 == 00000001 - all the same values in memory.  You would need the input parameter to be defined as a string, such as "0001", then you can count leading zeros.

Comment: @Dgrin91 typing mistake.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Be careful.  1 == 01, but 8 != 08, since that would result in a compiler error.

Comment: @HansZ int i = 0100 and int i = 100 do **not** get parsed to the same thing

Comment: @HansZ `int i = 0100;` is the same as `int i = 64;`, not `int i = 100;`

Comment: haha forgot about octal. that was a bad example on my part.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: Exactly the opposite is true -- the representation has a fixed number of bits, and fully half the possible values (including virtually ALL the commonly encountered values) have leading zeros.  For example, the representation of 10 is `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010`.

Comment: I was referring to a constant value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integers don't have leading zeros, they are of a fixed size. If you were to display any of those values you would see that all the leading zeros are dropped, since there's no way to know that they were there in the first place.

In addition, an integer literal with a leading zero is an *octal* constant, not a decimal one. You would see the `0100` displayed as 64, not 100.

If leading zeros are important to your application, you need to keep the value as a string instead of an integer.

Comment: @SteveJessop you're absolutely right, my phrasing was potentially confusing - thanks. I've added the missing word.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up the string representation of a number and its numeric representation. For 01, this can be written just as well as 1. Also, in C++ prefixing a number with zero makes it octal, so your last example 0100 is 64 in base 10, thus it's returning 2. If you want the length of a string representation of a number, look at converting a number to a string.

Comment: is there any function to convert an int to string

Comment: Yes, there's plenty of ways, but they're not going to put your zeroes on the front. Do a google search for converting ints to strings in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Integers do not get stored with preceding zeroes so there is no way to do this. You could, however, count the number of preceding zeroes in the string representation of an int.